# Find out which users liked a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If we go to developers.facebook.com, we can see:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/post

does anyone know, given a post with a postid, how I can find out which users liked (reacted to) the post?

Comment: be careful with tags, you tagged two different sdks in your question, while you don´t even use one of them somewhere in it. fixed the tags for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get any user data without specific authorization of that user. So, if no user authorized your App, most endpoints will most likely return an empty array. The comments endpoint will only return data that is not user specific, you will not even get a user id - just a comment id.

For example, the response for reactions of a Page Post that definitely has reactions and is public without any restrictions - the App being used even got "Page Public Content Access" approved:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "...",
      "after": "..."
    },
    "next": "..."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll to the bottom of the page it says:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/post

[image]